# pg_restore ERROR: “Relation does not exist” and creating new database

Tags: postgresql, psql, exists, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have made a backup of my specific tables that I want to restore into a new database using:

```sh
call pg_dump -Fc -h server -d database -U user -p password -v -f dump.sql -t public.table1 -t public.table2
```

And I have no problems.

I then want to restore the dump by creating a new database with pg_restore using:

```sh
call pg_restore --clean --create -d temp -h server -p password -U user dump.sql
```

This gives me a "database temp does not exist" error. This should have created the database and restored it as far as I understand.

I However then create the "temp" database manually and run:

```sh
call pg_restore --clean --create -d temp -h server -p password -U user dump.sql
```

This follows through, but does not create the tables and gives me an error "relation table1" and "relation table2" does not exist and only creates the corresponding id_sequences for the two tables.

What I actually want is to not have to manually create the new database and that all tables in the backup is restored into a brand new database via pg_restore using:

```sh
call pg_restore --clean --create -d temp -h server -p password -U user dump.sql
```

as I understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create the database `temp`, `pg_restore` needs to be connected to a *different* database first.

So it won't do to use `-d temp`; you must specify an existing database, typically `postgres`.

`pg_restore` will connect to that database, issue `CREATE DATABASE temp`, connect to `temp` and proceed to restore the data.

Answer (score -1):

for me, I installed pgAdmin 4 and did the restore via pgAdmin 4 UI, instead of doing it via cmd:

```
pg_restore -d <database_name> -p 5432 -Fc -O -a --no-tablespaces --no-privileges -v -U postgres -j 8 <database_name>.dmp
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: restore over the pgAdmin 4 UI